# Uri.parse and Uri.Builder give same uri but different result

Tags: android

I'm having a hard time figuring what's wrong here. I got an activity with this intent filter in it :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data
        android:scheme="launcher"
        android:host="custo"
        />
  </intent-filter>
```

I succesfully launch my activity by doing (paths and parameters are handled further in the code):

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("launcher://custo/3dw?iuid=06eec76c-f48e-4961-870e-4b27495f8201"));
```

But this one doesn't work :

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("launcher").appendEncodedPath("/custo").appendPath("3dw").appendQueryParameter("iuid", "f6f18a3d-14f9-4969-8a24-8130f4cad5d1").build();
context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```

Error is :

> can't start activity with intent "act=...action.VIEW dat="launcher://custo/3dw?iuid=06eec76c-f48e-4961-870e-4b27495f8201" (wich is the same string I parse).

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example, your [`Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) lacks an [`authority`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getAuthority()), which the framework must be looking for. It looks like a valid `Uri` at first, but instead of giving an authority, you are giving a path which makes your `Uri` look like the following (notice the missing `/` after the scheme) :

> launcher:/custo/3dw?iuid=f6f18a3d-14f9-4969-8a24-8130f4cad5d1

Your statement should be :

```
new Uri.Builder()
  .scheme("launcher")
  .authority("custo")
  .appendPath("3dw")
  .appendQueryParameter("iuid", "f6f18a3d-14f9-4969-8a24-8130f4cad5d1")
  .build();
```